# Why would we simulate baseband rather than passband

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, demodulation, baseband

My question is, Why do we usually use baseband in simulation rather than passband? however, if we want to test our simulated idea in real environment, it must be sometimes in passband !!

So, should simulation in baseband give the same results if we made it in passband? for term of BER, MSE and so on

Here is an example as asked in the first comments,

In baseband, Suppose you have ofdm system, with $s$ is the $n^{th}$ block with N symbol, when performing N-by-N FFT to get $x = FFT^Hs $, after adding a CP as guard interval with length P, we will have $M = x + P$ is the transmitted signal as baseband.

But in Passband, we will not transmit the $M$ as it's, we will have additional process when having $M$, this process is summarized  conversion --> matches filter --> carrier modulation by multiplying (.*exp(-j*2*pi*fc*t), fc is the carrier frequency t is the time period, and them transmit real part of this results, then in the receiver side, we follow the inverse of these steps till getting the baseband signal $M$ then, both passband and baseband will follow the same steps.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide an example that motivated this question?

Comment: @A_A an example is added into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OFDM or any other system, if you understood what is the difference between the baseband and passband, then you would decide by yourself if there is a difference or no. However, its already mentioned in above comments, you shouldn't have any major difference between simulating base-band and pass-band.

Now let me explain what are the base-band and pass-band, first be aware that the main difference between them is when using baseband, it means we transmit the signal as it is without doing modulation, but when using pass-band, we start doing modulation and shift the signal to be transmitted in frequency to be higher frequency and then transmit it. So you can notice, the pass-band signal is, in reality, a base-band. The alone thing to differentiate between them is that frequency shifting (Modulation ).

Here is additional explanation for them,

Almost  all  sources  of  information  generate  baseband  signals.  Baseband  signals are those that have frequencies relatively close to zero such as the human voice (20 Hz – 5  kHz)  and  the  video  signal  from  a  TV  camera  (0  Hz  –  5.5  MHz).  A  plot  of  an  audio  signal and its frequency spectrum are shown below, where it is seen that the most of the  power of the audio signal is concentrated in the frequency range from (0 – 4 kHz). The  telephone  system  used  for  homes  and  offices,  for  example,  may  transmit  the  baseband audio  signal  as  it  is  when  the  call  is  local  (from  your  home  to  your  neighbor’s  home). However,  when  the  telephone  call  is  a  long–distance  call  that  is  transmitted  via   microwave   or   satellite   links,   the   baseband   audio   signal   becomes   unsuitable   for   transmission  and  the  communication  system
becomes  a  passband  system.  Similarly, transmitting  the  video  signal  from  your  camera  to  your  TV  using  a  wire  represents  a   baseband  communication  while  transmitting  that  video  signal  via  satellites  passband  transmission.   Therefore,   baseband   transmission,   which   is   easier   than   passband transmission,  is  usually  used  when communicating  over  wires,  while  over–the–air  transmission   requires   passband transmission.   Notice   that   even   over   wires,   the transmission may be passband transmission in specific applications.

Answer (score 4):

One very obvious advantage of baseband simulation of communication systems is the low sampling rate it requires.

Considering a narrowband communication system having a few MHz of bandwidth to a few GHz of carrier frequency, it would be much easier (in terms of computation) to simulate it in the baseband sampling rate.

The reliability and the quality of a baseband simulation depends mostly on how accurate and realistic your mathematical modeling of the actual physical channel and the modulation system using it.

Comment: Thank you so much ..  but now, how about if we simulated the same signal in baseband and then in passband, will that give same results or almost the same results? regardless the sampling rate which will be higher when upsampling the transmitted signal.

Comment: The results should not depend on the sampling rate. But since every practical simulation has some limitations, therefore there could be (minor) differences.@Eng.Badr